# How does Android TextView.SetText(int resid) work?

Tags: java, android, textview, android-resources

This an example from Big Nerd Ranch Guide:

```
package com.example.geoquiz;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class QuizActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private Button mTrueButton;
    private Button mFalseButton;
    private Button mNextButton;
    private TextView mQuestionTextView;
    private TrueFalse[] mQuestionBank = new TrueFalse[] {
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_africa, true),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_americas, false),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_asia, false),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_mideast, true),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_oceans, true)
    };
    private int mCurrentIndex = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
        mTrueButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.true_button);
        mFalseButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.false_button);
        mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, R.string.incorrect_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, R.string.correct_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        mQuestionTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);
        int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getQuestion();
        mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.quiz, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The part in question is this:

```
    int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getQuestion();
    mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
```

`question` is an `int` here, I wonder how this works. More strangely, if I change `question` into a literal int, e.g. 1, then the app won't work.

Comment: What do you mean by how does it work?  All strings in `strings.xml` are associated with an integer value (resid = resource id).  When setText() takes an integer, it goes to look up the string resource that corresponds to that integer and update the `TextView`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)) I thought described this better so I'm not sure if they changed them recently (or since I last looked).

Anyway, when you supply an `int` as the `param` it refers to a `resource id`. So, if you have a `string resource` in your `strings.xml` you can supply it here instead of a literal `String`.

So, if in your `strings.xml` you have

```
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello!</string>
</resources>
```

you could do

```
myTV.setText(R.string.hello);
```

and `myTV` would show "Hello".

When you pass it an `int` that doesn't match an `id` in `R.strings` then you get the exception.

Answer (score 3):

The `Strings` you pre-define in the xml have dynamically generated ids in the `R.java` class. For example `R.string.question_africa` is an integer, pointing to your saved `String resource`. You can open the `R.java` class and see the exact integers that refer to your strings but it won't mean anything to you since they're automatically generated.

`setText()` method can be called on different variables, in your example is `setText(int resId)`, where `resId` is a resource id

More: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)